# Android error with value-specific styles.xml

Tags: android, api, android-studio, themes, manifest

I have an app that I want to support the Material theme with for Android L, as well as a normal theme for everything below. Right now, I have a `styles.xml` inside of the "values" folder which uses an app theme with a parent of `android:Theme.Holo.Light`, and a `styles.xml` inside of "values-v21" with an app theme with a parent of `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light`.

This works fine if I am compiling the app for Android L, but if I change the build.gradle and the Android Manifest to run the app with API 19 instead of Android L, I get the error `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light`.

What is it I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Themes and some framework resource files stored for individual APIs, so if set compileSdkVersion below 'android-L' means compiler will not retrieve the Meterial theme which belongs to android-L framework. You can set any minimum version and target version but the compileSdkVersion should be 'android-L'.